# Best method to call a stored procedure that returns multiple tables and then turn to List

Tags: stored-procedures, blazor

I am developing a Blazor server app. I have a stored procedure that contains a few tables. In order to do this in one hit, I found myself adding a column to the start of the table and loading this in via a dataset, eg

```
select 'Table1' as Table1, * 
from table1

select 'Table2' as Table2, * 
from table2
```

I load the Dataset and check each DataTable to see if the first column heading contains Table1 or Table2. I then convert this to DataTable to a list.

I wasn't sure if this was the best method to use. Are there any other methods I should consider or are more efficient? I also have Dapper and Newtonsoft included in my app.

Answer (score 0):

What have you written using dapper so far please?